# Gazebo Garden: change noise characteristics of IMU sensor

Tags: gazebo, imu

I am compiling Gazebo from source on my Ubuntu 22.04 Mac M1 Parallels VM.

I am wondering how I can change the noise characteristics (like standard deviation) of the default IMU sensor in Gazebo Garden.

I noticed that there is already a class that handles these IMU sensor changes, but I am unsure of how to use it. https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6.9/classignition_1_1gazebo_1_1Imu.html

Where would I insert this class? Would I treat like a plugin and put it into the SDF? I see it has something to do with the Component Inspector. Or would a different method be more convenient?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The noise characteristics can be configured through the [SDF](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=sensor#sensor_imu). Currently the following characteristics are supported:

- "none" (no noise)
- "gaussian" (draw noise values independently for each measurement from a Gaussian distribution)
- "gaussian_quantized" ("gaussian" plus quantization of outputs (ie. rounding)

It can be configured for the `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates for the [`angular velocity`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=sensor#imu_angular_velocity) and [`linear acceleration`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=sensor#imu_linear_acceleration).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Do you know how I can convert accel and gyro noise values from my real IMU sensor (velocity random walk 0.05 m/s/sqrt(hr), angular random walk 0.1 degrees/sqrt(hr), gyro bias instability, 3.5 degrees/hr, accel bias instability 0.1 mg) into Gazebo's SDF fields? Or can you link any documents that explains how to transfer random walk and bias instability into standard deviation, bias standard deviation, and dynamic bias correlation time?

Comment: You should probably create a new question for that.